# Changing the BitLocker password

Tags: windows, bitlocker, encryption

Is there any way to change the BitLocker password?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the recovery password without decrypting in one of two ways 1) using the manage-bde tool or 2) using the [Win32_EncryptableVolume WMI interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376483(VS.85).aspx). The first method doesn't require any programming/scripting so we'll go that route.

Assume X: is the BitLocker protected drive you want to change recovery password for.

1. Open an elevated cmd prompt
2. Type `manage-bde X: -protectors -get -type RecoveryPassword`
3. Locate the protector you want to cycle (probably the only one displayed) and copy its ID field (including the curly braces).
4. Type `manage-bde X: -protectors -delete -id [paste the ID you copied]`
5. Type `manage-bde X: -protectors -add -rp [optionally specify the new 48-digit password or enter nothing to have it randomly generated for you]`

And you're done! You've changed your recovery password.

Note: If you get an error when you try to delete the recovery password, this is likely because a recovery password is required by Group Policy on your system. To get around this, first suspend BitLocker with `manage-bde X: -protectors -disable` then after you've added the new recovery password, resume protection with `manage-bde X: -protectors -enable`.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways are available to change Bitlocker password.

- **Way 1: Change BitLocker password in File Explorer**

You just need to open File Explorer and right-click the BitLocker drive and select Change password option. Then you can change the password.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwfaW.png)

- **Way 2: Change BitLocker PIN or Password by Control Panel**

Open Control Panel window and go to BitLocker Drive Encryption option. Then find the BitLocker drive and select change password option. Then you can change the password.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJmSI.png)

- **Way 3: Change BitLocker PIN or Password via CMD**

Open CMD as administrator and type *manage-bde -changepassword*  command and hit Enter. Then type and confirm a new password. Finally, the password has been changed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc4QD.png)

More details can be referred to this post: [How to Change BitLocker PIN or Password in Windows 10](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/how-to-change-bitlocker-pin-or-password-in-windows-10.html)